# SED command giving error while replacing a string

Tags: linux, sed

I need to replace a string with another string in a file.

i have the below line a file.

```
tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH %TPCL_HOME%/lib/httpclient_3.0:%TPC
L_HOME%/lib:%RV_HOME%/lib:%TRA_HOME%/icjava/6.2/lib:%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%
```

i need to replace "tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH " with 
"tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH %RV_HOME%/lib/64:"

and finally the line should be

```
tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH %RV_HOME%/lib/64:%TPCL_HOME%/lib/httpclient_3.0:%TPC
L_HOME%/lib:%RV_HOME%/lib:%TRA_HOME%/icjava/6.2/lib:%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%
```

i tried with the below command but getting error sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unknown option to `s'

```
sed -i s/"tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/"tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH %RV_HOME%/lib/64:"/ bwengine.tra
```

can someone help in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern you want to replace or the replacement string contain the slash, use a different separator, e.g. `=`:

```
s="tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH "="tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH %RV_HOME%/lib/64:=
```

Answer (score 0):

you may think to use `&` as the matched string which will reduce the length of the sed command.

```
sed 's!tibco.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH !&%RV_HOME%/lib/64:!' file
```

refer this url: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html#uh-3